# Index is not being used after split partition

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

We have a table A with approx 400 million records with indexes:

- idx1 on column1
- idx2 on column2
- idx3 on column3

and partition on column4 like below.

part1 having data <='31-Dec-16'
and after that daily partitions are available.

**Then in UAT** we decided to split the partition Part1 into daily partitions but after that queries are performing slow on table A.

Its taking full table scan instead of index scan **in UAT** environment but **in prod** environment where split partitioning not implemented yet, index scanning is being performed.

Comment: You should also include examples of those queries

Answer (score 1):

When you split, merge, drop or truncate a partition, all *global* (non-local) indexes are immediately invalidated (the index segment is actually dropped since it contains invalid ROWIDs), and must then be rebuilt:

```
ALTER INDEX idx1 REBUILD PARALLEL (DEGREE 16) NOLOGGING;
ALTER INDEX idx2 REBUILD PARALLEL (DEGREE 16) NOLOGGING;
ALTER INDEX idx3 REBUILD PARALLEL (DEGREE 16) NOLOGGING;
```

Local indexes never invalidate as a whole, but during a partition split or merge, the index partition(s) impacted will be invalid, while the other partitions remain valid. If this is what has happened, unless your query prunes to a specific partition where the index it needs is still valid, a single invalid index partition will make the entire thing unusable by a query. Identify the invalid index partitions with:

```
SELECT index_name,partition_name
  FROM all_ind_partitions
 WHERE status = 'UNUSABLE'
```

And rebuild:

```
ALTER INDEX idx1 REBUILD PARTITION Jan2023 PARALLEL (DEGREE 16) NOLOGGING;
ALTER INDEX idx1 REBUILD PARTITION Feb2023 PARALLEL (DEGREE 16) NOLOGGING;
```

etc..

If you have a lot of partitions to do then a simple PL/SQL loop and `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` can rebuild them all quickly:

```
BEGIN
  FOR rec_part IN (SELECT index_name,partition_name
                     FROM all_ind_partitions
                    WHERE status = 'UNUSABLE'
                      AND index_name IN ('IDX1','IDX2','IDX3'))
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER INDEX "'||rec_part.index_name||'" REBUILD PARTITION "'||rec_part.partition_name||'" PARALLEL (DEGREE 16) NOLOGGING';
  END LOOP;
END;
```